# Get data from database and pass to view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In controller I am trying to get data from table, and then pass it to the view.

```
//controller
public function view($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::where('id', $id);

    return view('contact.edit', ['contact' => $contact]);
}

//view
@foreach($contact as $key=>$value)
    {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

But I get just empty page, and if I try to echo value with `{{ $contact->first_name}}` i just receive error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$first_name`.
I also tried to use find method, but got the same result. 
Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `home_phone` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `work_phone` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell_phone` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `best_phone` enum('home_phone','work_phone','cell_phone') NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Contact::find ->where(['id' => $id]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Might be because you're not using `->first();` after the query.

Not really sure why that wouldn't work, you can try this instead:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $contact = Contact::find($id);

    return view('contact.edit')->with('contact', $contact);
}
```

Then in your view you can access all properties like so:

```
{{$contact->id}}
{{$contact->first_name}}
//etc
```

Comment: Keep in mind, `get()` will not return a model, it will return a collection of models.

Comment: @Devon, Yes, thats why I suggested `find` because he was only getting one, by the ID. Just wanted to explain why the query was failing initially.

Comment: Right, but first() would be the comparable method to find(), not get.  Find just executes `where('primary key', $id)->first()`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Edited!

Answer (score 4):

`Contact::where('id', $id)` only prepares a query with the query builder.  You haven't yet executed the query or retrieved any results.

`Contact::where('id', $id)->first()` will execute the query and retrieve the first result, although since `id` is likely the primary key, `Contact::find($id)` is a quicker way to get the first result matching that id.